# Directly Approve Blog post with "Save as Draft" activated

Tags: 2013, publishing, blog, content-approval, draft

We have a SharePoint 2013 out of the box blog.

Because the user wants to have drafts, I activated the "Require content approval for submitted items" in the posts-list versioning settings.

But this leads now to the unwanted behaviour that the "Publish" button won't directly approve new blog posts. The post is saved but not approved - it is pending. The user or someone other needs an extra step (that they will probably forget sometimes) to approve the new blog post so others can see it.

It seems this was different in SharePoint 2010 (see point 6 in first section): http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/post-to-a-blog-HA010378204.aspx

Why is there a publish button when it doesn't publish it? It seems to do the same thing as "save as draft" button when drafts are activated. How can I directly publish/approve a new blog post with drafts activated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create permissions group in your sharepoint site that allows the specific people posting to this blog to be able post without the need for Approval.

Now if you use Microsoft Word, use the built in Blog Post template and connect this to your SharePoint site. (Open MS Word, New, Blog Post, Manage Accounts, New, SHarePoint blog, ) This will allow you to:

- post to categories
- publish as draft
- publish
- open previosly saved as draft
- Open previously posted
- publish previously saved as draft

The MS Blog Post template will also make the posting easier for the end user. Might be worth taking a look

Comment: Your proposal seems to work but isn't there a solution inside SharePoint without Word? This really seems like a bug not a "feature". "Publish" inside MS Word will publish the post and approve it, where "Publish" inside the SharePoint form will publish it but not approve it. What a mess.